# flutter invalid override, scroll indicator isnt valid override

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, overriding

I'm new to flutter and dart, and having a problem with override my custom widget.

here is my code,

```
class SBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

and this is my configuration.dart

```
 Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    switch (getPlatform(context)) {
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return child;
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        switch (androidOverscrollIndicator) {
          case AndroidOverscrollIndicator.stretch:
            return StretchingOverscrollIndicator(
              axisDirection: details.direction,
              child: child,
            );
          case AndroidOverscrollIndicator.glow:
            break;
        }
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
        break;
    }
    return GlowingOverscrollIndicator(
      axisDirection: details.direction,
      color: _kDefaultGlowColor,
      child: child,
    );
  }
```

and this is my error message:

```
'SBehavior.buildOverscrollIndicator' ('Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget, AxisDirection)') isn't a valid override of 'ScrollBehavior.buildOverscrollIndicator' ('Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget, ScrollableDetails)').dartinvalid_override
scroll_configuration.dart(180, 10): The member being overridden.
```

I don't understand what this mean is, and trying to find out how to fix it.

Please help

Thank you.